# Effect of pressure increase on electron orbital wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, wavefunction, electrons

One of my nuclear physics exercises was to find out if increasing the pressure of a sample of $^{7}\textrm{Be}$ would increase the chance of electron capture to $^{7}\textrm{Li}$ occur. My reasoning was that the electron wave function is not pressure dependent and therefor it would not increase the likelihood of an electron capture.

But I know that increasing the pressure does change the likelihood of electron capture. My question is how does increasing the pressure influence the wave function of the electron in orbit? My quantum mechanics class did not cover this and I could not find anything on the web about this.

Comment: Usually we compute orbital wave-function for atoms in isolation. When you bring two close together there will be a van der Walls interaction, altering both charge distributions into little dipoles. I think the things to think about (1) can you model that in a perturbative way (2) how close do you have to be before it becomes interesting and (3) how sensitive is it to changes in mean inter-atomic distance?

Comment: You mean finding out how the wave function of the electron changes when you add the potential of the dipole of another atom that is close to it? I do know that the electron capture increases for very high pressures (in the order of kbar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One model is to say that the atom is in an impenetrable spherical box, and solve for the wavefunctions.

See Y P Varshni [Accurate wavefunctions for the confined hydrogen atom at high pressures](http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-4075/30/18/001/fulltext/) J. Phys. B: At. Mol. Opt. Phys. 30 No 18 (28 September 1997) L589-L593.

The Fermi Contact Term (electron density at the nucleus) greatly increases as the size of the spherical box decreases (pressure increase).  Electron capture is due to Fermi contact.